# Removing duplicate values in table chart

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I would like to ask for your assistance, the table chart shows duplicate values but in power query it is just unique. Is there are DAX formula where it will be distinct in the table chart? Apologies as I am new to power bi. Please see sample images

[I want to remove or now display the "0" value with duplicate competency.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLEBa.png)

Thank you

[I want to remove or now display the "0" value with duplicate competency.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLEBa.png)

Comment: It's incredibly difficult to answer your question without more information. What does your data model look like? What does your data look like? What are you showing in the visualization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this simple DAX code as a new measure:

```
Value Measure = 
VAR _val = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Value] )
RETURN
IF ( _val <> 0 , _val )
```

Use the measure in your table visualization together with the `'Table'[Competency]` column, and remove the `'Table'[Value]` column from the visual.

This removes all the competencies with zero-values - not sure if that is what you were after, or if you only wanted to remove exactly duplicates, that requires a slightly different formula, like this:

```
Advanced Value Measure =
VAR _good_symbol =
    UNICHAR ( 10003 )
VAR _bad_symbol =
    UNICHAR ( 10007 )
VAR _sum =
    SUMX ( 'Table', IF ( 'Table'[Value] = _good_symbol, 1 ) )
VAR _is_distinct =
    HASONEVALUE ( 'Table'[Competency] )
RETURN
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        _is_distinct
            && _sum > 0, _good_symbol,
        _is_distinct
            && _sum = 0, _bad_symbol
    )
```

This will show all the competencies, but assign a `✗` to the competencies that have no rows with `✓`.

Answer (score -1):

In Power Query do the following steps

1. First merge Competency and Value columns. Merge here means concatenate both columns.
2. Write a step in M code to remove rows containing "Business Process Management0".
3. Finally remove Merged column.

M code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Ashok\Power BI\Stack Overflow\Data_09jun23.xlsx"), null, true),
    Data_Sheet = Source{[Item="Data",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Data_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Competency", type text}, {"Value", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Inserted Merged Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Merged", each Text.Combine({[Competency], Text.From([Value], "en-US")}, ""), type text),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows( #"Inserted Merged Column", each let thisrep = [Merged] in List.Count(List.Select({"Business Process Management0"}, each Text.Contains(thisrep, _))) = 0),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Merged"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Note: Used 1 in place of check mark.

Comment: I think it's fairly clear from the first sentence in the question that it is not a "remove duplicates in Power Query"-problem, and that your solution is therefore incorrect.